# Wiring embedded at the bottom of a wall

Tags: electrical, walls, flooring, hardwood-floor

[image: wiring under walls]

The white wall is a party wall in a row house - my plan was just to repair the plaster on the wall.  The other wall is an exterior wall that is plaster on brick and mortar. I plan to put up some 2 polyiso board with the wiring underneath as well.  Also I will put a new hardwood floor after it is all done.  Just want to make sure I am not doing a major no no in regards to the wiring.

If not is the some I can do with the wiring before I finish the walls?

Comment: How is this party wall constructed?  I'm not sure if putting cabling in shallow chases is legal in a fire-rated assembly...

Comment: Party wall is probably triple wythe at least with plaster on top of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that 90 degree bend the wire takes in corner?  That would be cause to have the wire rerouted.  If the casing shows any sign of having been crimped that would be cause to have it replaced.

Since we know the wire needs to be rerouted, how it is rerouted should take care of the issue of protecting it from nails and other sources of damage.